# Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework

i'm trying to make a login in zend framework, but PDO is giving me an error.
I have the following function :

```
public function isCorrectLogin (Application_Model_User $user){

    $row = $this->_db_table->fetchRow(
                $this->_db_table
                     ->select()
                     ->where( array ('email = ?' => $user->email,
                                     'password = ?' => sha1(SALT.$user->password)))
                           );

    if(empty($row)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;                
}
```

In my controller i use this function :

```
$oUserActions = new Application_Model_UserMapper();

            $user = new Application_Model_User();
            $user->email = $_REQUEST['email'];          
            $user->password = $_REQUEST['password'];

            if($oUserActions->isCorrectLogin($user)){                   
                echo 'validated';                   
            }
```

Im getting this error :

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Stack trace:

#0 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array)
#3 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1575): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#4 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1437): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#5 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\application\models\UserMapper.php(49): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#6 C:\webserver\htdocs\photo\application\controllers\LoginController.php(31): Application_Model_UserMapper->getUserLogin(Object(Application_Model_User))
```

Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using an array?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch-models-and-integrating-doctrine-orm/ because i followed this tutorial a bit and they do it here as well

Comment: you're not using it the same way they do $this->_db_table->update($data, array('id = ?' => $user_object->id)); they have two parameters, the first one being the associative array containing the input fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Why are you using an array.

```
$select->where(
        $db->quoteInto('email = ?', => $user->email) . ' AND ' . $db->quoteInto('password = ?', sha1(SALT.$user->password))
    );
    // $db is your instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_*
    // You can get it from a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract 
    //subclass by calling its getAdapter() method
```